# Find a Cauchy sequence that does not converge

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

I am supposed to look at $l_0$, the set of all sequences with finitely many non-real elements in $(l_0,d_{\infty})$. It is just that I don't quite understand how the $d_\infty$-metric is defined on sequences(and basically else, it would be nice if anyone could elaborate...).

If you look at the sequence $\{x_n\} = (\frac{1}{n},0,0,....,)$, this is clearly a Cauchy-sequence, is it then so that the supremum of all the numbers in the sequence will converge to 1?

EDIT: In my notes, i have defined $d_{\infty}(x,y) = \max_{1 \leq j \leq n} |x_j - y_j|$

Answer (score 3):

Try the sequence $x_n = (1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, \dots, 1/n, 0, 0, 0, \dots )$.

Comment: But doesn't that converge to (0,0,0,...)?

Comment: It is trying to converge to $(1, 1/2, 1/3, \dots)$ which is not in $l_0$.

Comment: But I thought you were speaking of convergence in terms of the metric, such that the convergence in this case will rather be $1 + \frac{1}{2} + ...$, I just want to get rid of all the misunderstandings.

Comment: @user134489 Measure the distance between consecutive points.